# mysql query to take sum from another table and select

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, I want to build one query to select only results from orders where the quantity is not fulfilled by table deliveries:

table `orders`:

```
id item quantity
1  a    15
2  b    5
3  c    6
```

table `deliveries`:

```
id order_id quantity
1  2        3
2  2        1
3  2        1
4  3        3
```

I want it something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` 
WHERE `quantity`>(SELECT SUM(`quantity`) 
FROM `deliveries` 
WHERE `order_id`=orders.id);
```

result should be something like this:

```
id item quantity
1  a    15
3  c    6
```

Comment: what do you want to do? I can't understand the table. You want to get the orders that are already done? meaning if all the orders are already delivered? or the orders that are not yet completed?

Answer (score 1):

If order table has only one row per order, try the below query. I think you also need to have orders for which no deliveries have been made.

```
SELECT 
    ord.*
FROM orders ord LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT 
    order_id, sum(quantity) AS 'totalDelivered'
   FROM 
    deliveries 
   GROUP BY order_id) 
    AS delv 
   ON ord.id = delv.order_id
WHERE (delv.totalDelivered < ord.quantity OR delv.order_id IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create table orders
(   id int not null,
    item varchar(100) not null,
    quantity int not null
);
insert orders values 
(1,'a',15),
(2,'b',5),
(3,'c',6);

create table deliveries
(   id int not null,
    order_id int not null,
    quantity int not null
);
insert deliveries values
(1,2,3),
(2,2,1),
(3,2,1),
(4,3,3);
```

query:

```
select o.id,o.item,o.quantity as quant_ordered,ifnull(sum(d.quantity),0) as delivered 
from orders o 
left join deliveries d 
on d.order_id=o.id 
group by o.id,o.item,o.quantity 
having delivered<quant_ordered;

+----+------+---------------+-----------+
| id | item | quant_ordered | delivered |
+----+------+---------------+-----------+
|  1 | a    |            15 |         0 |
|  3 | c    |             6 |         3 |
+----+------+---------------+-----------+
```

The `having` clause allows one to use the alias'd column name.

Answer (score 1):

You can try in this way also:

```
SELECT o.id, o.item, o.quantity
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
    o1.id, 
    IFNULL(SUM(d.quantity), 0) quantity 
FROM orders o1
LEFT JOIN deliveries d ON d.order_id = o1.id
GROUP BY d.order_id) p ON p.id = o.id
AND o.quantity > p.quantity
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the use of "WHERE 'quantity'>(SELECT SUM('quantity')"? You are getting the sum of all the quantity tables so it is not possible to get one result. Your query should be something like this:

This will get all the deliveries done or completed:

```
SELECT orders.* FROM orders INNER JOIN deliveries ON orders.id=deliveries.order_id WHERE orders.quantity=deliveries.quantity
```

or

This will get all the deliveries that is not yet done or completed:

```
    SELECT orders.* FROM orders INNER JOIN deliveries ON orders.id=deliveries.order_id WHERE orders.quantity>deliveries.quantity
```